# Does "DefaultCharSetAttribute" apply to "StructLayoutAttribute.CharSet" too?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport, structlayout

C# default platform invoke uses ANSI marshalling both for method parameters and struct fields strings.

System.Runtime.InteropServices contains an attribute "DefaultCharset" to change it to Unicode.

From MSDN: "Apply the DefaultCharSetAttribute attribute at the assembly level or module level to set the CharSet value for any call to DllImportAttribute that does not include a CharSet named argument specified by the user."

My question is: does this attribute set the default for "StructLayoutAttribute.CharSet" too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try it:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[module: DefaultCharSet(CharSet.Unicode)]

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var sla = typeof(Foo).StructLayoutAttribute;
        Console.WriteLine(sla.CharSet);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

struct Foo { };
```

Output:

```
  Unicode
```

So yes.